# Mysql using variable in select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a rather involved query because I'm trying to keep the math out of the application code and in the query. I am trying to set a variable in the select and then re-use it in the same select. Unfortunately, any of my columns where I use these variables is returning null where there should be data. Everything else is working fine.

```
SELECT @signups:= COUNT(registrations.id) as signups, 
      @registrations:= SUM(IF(registrations.fees_paid_by_users = '1', registrations.amount - registrations.databar_fees - registrations.taxes - registrations.extras_price + registrations.discount_total, registrations.amount - registrations.taxes - registrations.extras_price + registrations.discount_total)) as registrations,
      @activities:= SUM(registrations.extras_price) as activities,
      @coupons:= SUM(discount_total) as coupons,
      @subtotal:= @registrations + @activities - @coupons as subtotal,
      @fees_not_paid_by_user:= SUM(IF(registrations.fees_paid_by_users = '0', registrations.databar_fees, 0)) as fees_not_paid_by_user,
      @taxes:= SUM(registrations.taxes) as taxes,
      @total_including_taxes:= @subtotal - @fees_not_paid_by_user + @taxes as total_including_taxes,
       events.name, 
       event_forms.title ,
       event_forms.id,
       CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) as user_name
FROM registrations, 
     events, 
     event_forms, 
     transactions,
     users
WHERE transactions.date >= '2013-09-01 00:00:00' 
AND transactions.date <= '2013-09-30 23:59:59'
AND registrations.transaction_id = transactions.id
AND registrations.event_forms_id = event_forms.id
AND event_forms.event_id = events.id
AND events.owner_id = users.id
GROUP BY registrations.event_forms_id
ORDER BY user_name ASC, name ASC, title ASC
```

In the above query, the `subtotal` and the `total_including_taxes` columns are returning null, I'm assuming because the query cannot access the previously defined variables.

This is my first time really using MySQL's user variables (I'm a developer, not a DBA) and I'm unsure if I'm doing something wrong and if so, how to fix it. I can do the math in the code if I need to, but I would really like to keep it on the database server as it is much beefier than the app server and can handle this easier.

Comment: Unfortunately, the previous variables are undefined. And you'll have either to substitute the formulas instead of them. Or calculate in the code (the best option).

Comment: Looks like you're right. Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this problem? I've run into the same issue where I have a lot of math to do but I also want to filter results based on the values of some of the variables, so doing it in a query is preferable as I can exactly control the number of results returned.

Answer (score 0):

Given your query, you're doing SUM(SUM(...)). SUM's intended for adding together field values, and I kind of doubt that variables will do the same thing e.g..

```
SELECT ..
   @foo := SUM(...),
   @bar := SUM(@foo)
```

might as well just be

```
   @bar := @bar + @foo
```

Comment: Sorry, I had pasted the wrong version of the query. The correct version is now there and I have already removed those extra SUM()s but still getting null in those columns.

Comment: Check that the insdividual items you're adding/subbing together to make those variables aren't themselves null. sql `null` is "contagious" and makes anything else its involved in `null` as well. it's literally "unknown", and "known + unknown = unknown".

Comment: @Kevin If what @MarcB said is your case, you may treat `null` values with [IFNULL()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull), like so: `SUM(IFNULL(maybeNullColumn, 0))`. This way your query will sum i.e. `1 + 3 + 0 + 2 = 6` instead of `1 + 3 + NULL + 2 = NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the previous variables in the query are undefined. You'll have either to substitute the formulas instead of them. Or to the next variables calculate in the code.